# (stability-theoretic) ¨weakly normal groups" are closed under subgroups

Tags: model-theory, algebraic-groups, stability-theory

Let me first introduce two definitions:

1. For a structure $\mathcal{M}$ in a language $\mathscr{L}$ and a subset $X \subseteq M^n$, the fully induced structure on $X$ is a structure $\mathcal{X}$ with the universe $X$ in a language consisting of following relational symbols: For every formula $\varphi (\overline{x}_1, \dots, \overline{x}_m)$, where $\overline{x}_1, \overline{x}_n, \dots, \overline{x}_m$ are $n$-tulpes of variables (all pairwise distinct), there is a rel. symbol $R_{\varphi}(y_1, \dots, y_m)$ interpreted in $\mathcal{X}$ as $\varphi(M) \cap X^m$.
2. Consider a (commutative) group $G$ to be an $\mathscr{L}$-strure, where $\mathscr{L}$ is an extension of the language of groups. $G$ is called *weakly normal* provided that every definable set $X \subseteq G^n$ is a finite Boolean combination of cosets of definable subgroups of $G^n$. (Definability is meant wrt the language $\mathscr{L}$).

These definitions are taken from the survey article "[Diophantine geometry from model theory](https://math.berkeley.edu/~scanlon/papers/bsl4ap00.pdf)" by Thomas Scanlon.

In the article the author claims that

> If G is a weakly normal group, then the induced structure on any
>   subgroup is also weakly normal.

(Page 8, 2nd paragraph; he actually writes "is also weakly minimal," but from the context it is obvious that it is meant "weakly normal".)

From the context it seems most likely that the language on the subgroup considered is the induced one from the original group.

My question is simply

> How does one see that this is true?

It is certainly true provided that the subgroup (let's call it $H$ inside a weakly normal group $G$) is definable (in $G$): whenever $X=\varphi(H)\subseteq H^m$, one can produce formula $\psi$ in the language of the group $G$ from $\varphi$ by replacing every predicate $R_{\sigma}(x_1, \dots, x_k)$ simply by the formula $\sigma(x_1, \dots, x_k)$, replacing quantifiers $\forall x$ by $\forall x \in H$ and finally replacing $\exists x$ by $\exists x \in H$. Then $\psi(G)\cap H=\varphi(H)$ and one uses the weak normality of $G$.

However, I have trouble seeing how does one make similar process to work without definability of $H$ or other extra assumptions (e.g. QE for the group $G$). Yet from what follows, $H$ not being definable seems to be pretty much standard situation.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In your definition of weakly normal, did you mean a finite union? Any set is the union of cosets of the trivial group.

Comment: @tomasz: Sorry, I provided wrong definition. Please, see the corrected version.

Comment: I don't see what's the problem? It seems pretty straightforward. If you take any definable set in $H^n$, just look at the definable set in $G^n$ whose trace it is, take the boolean combination witnessing weak normality of $G$ for that set, and then intersect that with $H^n$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, you mean to say that there may be more definable sets in $H$ with induced structure than just the traces of those sets which are definable in $G$?

Comment: @tomasz: Yes, exactly. I do not see how are sets definable by formulas like "$\exists x R_{\varphi}(x,y)$" (for example) traces of definables if I cannot say "$\exists x \in H: \varphi(x,y)$" (in $G$).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. To me, it looks like the right assumption would be that the induced structure of $H$ has quantifier elimination, syntactic assumptions about $G$ seem entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Meta remark: [about the stability-theory tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21103/147263).